# How many consecutive cell divisions are required to form the adult human body from the single cell zygote?

Tags: human-biology, development, embryology

The preferred question would have been what is the total number of cells in a full term human foetus and how many cell divisions are required to reach that number. However estimates of total cell numbers in foetus could not be found. From the abstract of the [July 5, 2013](http://informahealthcare.com/doi/abs/10.3109/03014460.2013.807878) article published in Annals of Human Biology, the adult human body consists of approximately $3.72 \times 10^{13}$ cells (37.2 Trillion). The question is: what would be the approximate number of cell divisions required to reach that number (Ignoring the fact that different tissues may reach full differentiation at different times)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like just a math problem if you allow that cells dying and different rates of division are not to be accounted for:

$2^N = 40 \times 10^{12}$

$log_2(40 \times 10^{12}) = N$

$N = 45.185$

so 45 or so divisions.

is that what you are looking for?

Comment: I think you want 40T, not 4T.

Comment: @ shigeta - Isn't 45 pretty close to the 'Hayflick limit'?

Comment: @RamManoharM Supposedly it's between 40-60, so yeah.  But if that means anything...

Comment: @ Amory - By the time you are 20 (young adult) your have near exhausted the capabilty for cell division (broadly speaking). Just wondering if the loss of Telomere has more important role during development other than merely ushering in senescence.

Comment: The Hayflick limit is entirely unrelated to this issue as the foetus develops firstly from embryonic totipotent stem cells, then pluripotent stem cells, and even in the adult body there are still multipotent stem cells, some of which are capable of indefinite replication.

Comment: that still leads me to the question of how does a whale get so big?  are the cells larger or how does a very large organism obey the hayflick limit? is it multipotent cells reasserting themselves to regenerate the tissue?

Comment: @shigeta I'm not sure what the answer is for whales specifically, but different species can have different telomere lengths. In fact, different *people* can be born with different telomere lengths. The Hayflick limit of 40-60 divisions is a statement about homo sapien cells.